# Reading customer data from excel into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, vsto

I am new to coding and I am trying to get information (Id num, name , birthday) of every customer into their own array. So far I am able to read the data from excel I just do not know how to **store it in an array** and I am not sure how to **convert "valueArray" from an object to a string array**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Reference to Excel Application.
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path.GetFullPath("excelpractice1.xlsx"));

    // Get the first worksheet.
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

    // Get the range of cells which has data.
    Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

    // Get an object array of all of the cells in the worksheet with their values.
    object[,] valueArray = (object[,])xlRange.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

    // iterate through each cell and display the contents.
    for (int row = 1; row <= xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; ++row)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(valueArray[row, row].ToString());
    } 

    // Close the Workbook.
    xlWorkbook.Close(false);

    // Relase COM Object by decrementing the reference count.
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

    // Close Excel application.
    xlApp.Quit();

    // Release COM object.
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
String[,] arr = new String[xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count,xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count];
for (int row = 1; row <= xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; ++row)
{
      for (int col = 1; col <= xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; ++col)
      {
        arr[row,col] = valueArray[row, col].ToString();
      } 
}
```

You can also use `Array.Copy` like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5d525b76-f5b6-4340-a899-c3c82570d2e1/is-there-a-twodimensional-arraycopy-method-?forum=netfxbcl).

Btw. not sure but I think you should need to also release `xlRange`